# "Кто" или "что" в предложении "Лица тех, кто/что любимы были мной"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

> ...лица тех, кто(что) любимы были мной. 
>   В данном случае - кто или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При множественном числе глагола, на мой взгляд, естественнее "что" (тех, что = тех людей/женщин, *которые*):

> ... лица тех, что были любимы мной

При единственном числе глагола - иначе (тех, кто = каждого/-ой из тех, *кто*):

> ... лица тех, кто мною был любим